# Instant Messager that supports video and voice chat

Tags: software-recommendation, instant-messaging

Are there any instant messengers for Ubuntu that support video and audio chat?

Answer (score 14):

[Empathy](http://live.gnome.org/Empathy) and [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im) support video and audio chats over Google Talk/Jabber/XMPP protocol. You could also give the recently launched [Google Video and Voice Chat](http://www.google.com/chat/video) an try.

[Skype](http://www.skype.com) also supports video and voice chat on Linux.

Or you could use [Ekiga](http://www.ekiga.orgmemory-friendly.) (VoIP client) for video and voice.

[Gyachi](http://gyachi.sourceforge.net/screenshots.shtml) has this on their web page:

> This Yahoo! client for Linux operating
>   system supports almost all of the
>   features you would expect to find on
>   the official Windows Yahoo! client:
>   Voice chat, webcams, faders,
>   'nicknames', audibles, avatars,
>   display images, and more. Yet, it
>   remains very light-weight and
>   memory-friendly.memory-friendly.

[Meebo](http://www.meebo.com/) is a web service that supports voice and video chats on Linux.

Comment: i want somthing for windows live......MSN

Comment: It seems Microsoft changed A/V chat protocols earlier this year and as a result aMSN and Empathy don't support A/V chats with MSN anymore.

Comment: I gave it a +1 because it really support google talk and facebook.