# What's the best chat client?

Tags: software-recommendation

I've recently switched to Ubuntu from windows, and I'm looking for alternatives for GTalk and windows Live messenger.

So which chat client do you use most?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2837/instant-messager-that-supports-video-and-voice-chat

Answer (score 3):

Pidgin will allow you to use almost any instant messaging protocol, which includes but not limits to GTalk and Windows Live Messenger. However, you may miss some WLM and/or GTalk functions/abilities.

Good luck!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Empathy is pretty good as the default IM of Ubuntu 10.10 and their is always pidgin

```
sudo apt-get install pidgin
```